# 'zsh: killed python' while executing python from Pipenv virtualenv on macOS Big Sur for Python 2.7

Tags: python, virtualenv, pipenv, macos-big-sur

1. Run `pipenv run python`

   Result : `zsh: killed pipenv run python` and Python shell not launched

Also same issue when doing following :-

```
pipenv install --python 2.7
pipenv shell
python
```

NOTE: No issue for Python 3.8 (coming with Big Sur default)  `pipenv install --python 3.8`

More Info:-

1. Big Sur version is 11.0 Beta (20A5354i)
2. Pipenv and Python (defaults) details :-

   Pipenv version: `'2020.8.13'`

   Pipenv location: `'/Users/ab/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pipenv'`

   Python location: `'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python'`

   Python installations found:

   3.8.2: `/usr/bin/python3`

   2.7.16: `/usr/bin/python2.7`

   2.7.16: `/usr/bin/python2`
3. Also tried by cleaning virtualenv `pipenv --rm` but same issue. Applying recent OS update too did not help.

Anyone got success with pipenv with default python 2.7 on Big Sur ?

Comment: Please provide steps to reproduce this issue. That said, also ask yourself if you don't want to create a bug ticket instead of a question here.

Comment: Thanks Ulrich. I raised this issue with Pipenv project also. I asked here to see if anyone also encountered similar bug and if any workaround / resolution.

Comment: Any update on this?  I'm hitting the same problem, thanks.

Comment: Same problem. Any leads?